# Display encrypted content on my website

Tags: plugins, customization, javascript, email, encryption

Good day

I am new here and to wordpress as well, please can someone tell me how i can automatically hide email addresses displayed on the front page(dynamic Content), see example https://quickleads.co.za/ is there a plugin or something?

e.g manjerat@gmail.com to m****t@gmail.com

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20545505/11584403